# Como realizar um select que traga dados duplicados dentro de uma coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Tenho uma tabela de itens em que alguns itens estão com algumas informações duplicadas, um simples DISTINCT resolveria, o problema é que a informação que está duplicada dentro da coluna, vai da posição 4 até a 7, por exemplo

tabela_itens

09423493

05**2205**01

09**2205**04

09923639

10928909

O que está em Négrito seria a informação duplicada que eu queria exibir como resultado do SELECT

Comment: eita se confundiu tudo, exemplo: `05220501` e `09220504` é pra trazer somente 1 deles?

Comment: No caso eu gostaria de saber todas as linhas desssa coluna que existe informações duplicadas, que considere da posição 4 até a 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você adicionou duas tags `sql-server` e `oracle`, é preciso saber qual o banco porque a sintaxe muda de um para outro, vou apresentar a sintaxe para os dois bancos:

- `SQL-SERVER`: pode usar a função [`SUBSTRING()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) para extrair o valor entre as posições 4 e 7

`select distinct(substring(codigo,3,4)) from tabela_itens`

- `ORACLE`: pode usar a função [`SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm), que tem a mesma sintaxe do anterior

`select distinct(substr(codigo,3,4)) from tabela_itens;`

Aqui pode ver um exemplo funcionando: [https://sqlfiddle.com/](https://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ae1e3/3)

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado. Tenho um banco em SQL SERVE e outro em Oracle, como você passou as duas sintaxe vou usar no dois bancos.

Comment: top, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta :)